# Executing PHP scripts using a button from Android app

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a simple app with two buttons each of which would execute a PHP script on my DB, on localhost. So far i have the php script working as intended (tested in browser):

```
<?php
require 'Connect.php'; // connects to DB

$query = "UPDATE tracker_database
SET tracker_logged_in = '1'
WHERE tracker_username = 'tracker01'";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
    echo'Success';
} else {
    echo'not executed';
}
?>
```

here I have the app's OnClickListener

```
public void addListenerOnExeBtn() {
    btn_exe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_exe);
    btn_exe.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String link = "http://10.0.3.2/path/to/my/script.php"; //using this IP for Genymotion emulator
                    new updateData().execute(link);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Executed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

And as far as I understand you need to use AsyncTask to access the scripts

```
private class updateData extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConn.connect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So my problem is that when I run my app and click the btn_exe it prints out the Toast "Executed" but when I refresh my DB there are no changes, and yes I put the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml. I can't find anything wrong in the logcat, no errors, nothing. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if your request from Android even started phpscript? Try to return something from php script and read it in Android, for start you can read responseCode from your urlConn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to fix the problem and it was in the updateData method, here is the fixed version if anyone has the same problem:

```
public class updateData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            URL url;
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if( conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            }else{
                InputStream err = conn.getErrorStream();
            }
            return "Done";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```